# How to get module name without its parents

Tags: python, logging

I'm setting up logging for my project, and I would like to set up loggers at the beginning of my modules. Currently I'm doing this:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__.split('.')[-1])
```

My question is that is there a better way of getting just the module name, without the upstream modules? (In my software it would be redundant to have that information in the log messages)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that the logging system has a federated configuration system and your trick pretty much deactivates it? You will not be able to do configuration per package or parent package anymore.

Comment: This is something that the documentation suggest. Do you suggest to use just one logger and communicate the place of origin by some other means?

Comment: Use the normal `__name__` for the logger. That means if your module is `a.b.c` configurations of `a` and `a.b` will also apply if not overwritten. You don't need to configure every single module in a package.